# Проблемы с последовательностью операций jQuery в IE7

Tags: jquery

Как решить проблему банальной последовательности операций jquery в IE7?

Код:

```
$('.zonekat li').hover(function(){  

    var thisin = $(this).html();
    alert(thisin);  
    $(this).append("<div></div>");

}
```

По наведению на элемент происходит две операции (алерт для отладки).

1. Кеширование исходного html кода элемента в переменную thisin;
2. Добавление в элемент div.

Проблема возникает в IE7, когда эти две операции происходят одновременно без цепочки последовательности и в переменную thisin кешируется код с добавленным div.

Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это весь код для hover, то у вас он срабатывает дважды - на hover и leave.
Может быть вы второй вызов считаете ошибочным... У меня в IE9 при browser mode IE7 работает как написано, т.е. правильно.

напишите:

```
$('.zonekat li').hover(function(){

    var thisin = $(this).html();
    alert(thisin);  
    $(this).append("<div></div>");

},function(){});
```

может быть проблема пропадет...

ЗЫ [.hover() - jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: Думаю, что если обратного действия для hover нет, то лучше вообще его не использовать, а отлавливать событие **mouseover** или **mouseenter**

Comment: Спасибо.
Проблема решается простановкой события mouseover или mouseenter

Comment: Вэлкам! Извините, что на чистейшем ангийском ))